# scatter chart google visualization doesn't handle my json

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

For some reason the following code doesn't deliver the expected google scatter chart. The JSON url has number output for both table variables. Any clue (by the way the JSON does work for the piechart, including one string variable instead of a number variable for the Scatter chart).

```
$(function() { 
     // when document loads, grab the json
     $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {
         // once grabbed, we run this callback

         // setup the new table and its data
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             data.addRows(data.rows.length);  // length gives us the number of results in our returned data
             data.addColumn('number', 'meterprijs');
             data.addColumn('number', 'perceeloppervlak');

         // now we need to build the map data, loop over each result
         $.each(data.rows, function(i,v) {
             // set the values for both the name and the population
             data.setValue(i, 0, v.a1_meterprijs);
             data.setValue(i, 1, v.a1_buitenopp);
         });
         // finally, create the map!

var options = {
      title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
      hAxis: {title: 'Meterprijs', minValue: 1500, maxValue: 6000},
      vAxis: {title: 'Perceelopp', minValue: 10, maxValue: 1000},
      legend: 'none'
    };        


         var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(
           document.getElementById('visualization2'));
              chart.draw(data, options);

          });
        });
       });
      });
```

Comment: You're right Mike. Just started doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here is the code which is working. The initial setup was fine but I've changed:

1) the chart map is named 'mapje' instead of data which is for the sake of rationality (a chart is not data, but the data itself are)
2) the table needs to be filled with numbers, so when the json parses numbers as strings (between " and "),  these have to be read as numbers by adding + before the variable (v.a1_meterprijs eg.).

So after all the initial code might have worked for some, but this one works for me:

```
$(function() { 
     // when document loads, grab the json
     $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {
         // once grabbed, we run this callback

         // setup the new table and its data
         var mapje = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             mapje.addRows(data.rows.length);  // length gives us the number of results 
             in our returned data
             mapje.addColumn('number', 'Perceelopp');
             mapje.addColumn('number', 'Meterprijs');

         // now we need to build the map data, loop over each result
         $.each(data.rows, function(i,v) {
             // set the values for both the name and the population
             mapje.setValue(i, 0, + v.a1_buitenopp);
             mapje.setValue(i, 1, + v.a1_meterprijs);
         });
         // finally, create the map!

var options = {
      title: 'Meterprijs vs Perceeloppervlak',
      hAxis: {title: 'Perceelopp', minValue: 10, maxValue: 1000},
      vAxis: {title: 'Meterprijs', minValue: 1500, maxValue: 6000},
      legend: 'none'
    };  



         var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(
           document.getElementById('visualization2'));
              chart.draw(mapje, options);

          });
        });
       });
      });
```